# How to save vgg model in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have to following model:

```
   #load VGG16 as convolutional base
    conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                      include_top=False,
                      input_shape=(150, 150, 3))
    
checkpoint_filepath = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Deep_Learning/models/Benign_Melign_VGG_noAug_final.h5"

model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_loss',
    mode='auto',
    save_best_only=True)

#add custom fully-connected network on top of the already-trained base network 
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

#freeze convolutional base 
conv_base.trainable = False

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
            optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3), # lr = 0.0001
            metrics=METRICS) 

#train fully-connected added part 
history = model.fit(train_generat.flow(train_dataset_split,
                                       train_labels_split,
                                       batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                       shuffle=False),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(train_dataset_split) // BATCH_SIZE, 
                    epochs=100,
                    validation_data=valid_generat.flow(valid_dataset_split,
                                       valid_labels_split,
                                       batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                       shuffle=False),
                    validation_steps=len(valid_labels_split) // BATCH_SIZE,
                    callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback])


model.summary()
model.save('Benign_Melign_VGG_noAug_final.h5')
```

the error is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in get_config(self)
    719       raise NotImplementedError('Layer %s has arguments in `__init__` and '
    720                                 'therefore must override `get_config`.' %
--> 721                                 self.__class__.__name__)
    722     return config
    723 

NotImplementedError: Layer ModuleWrapper has arguments in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config`.
```

there is a problem in the last line when I want to save the model. then I also need to load it later. I need to save and load the whole model, not just the weights. can you help e with this?

Comment: *there is a problem in the last line*, what exactly is the problem? You need to be specific, we can not guess the error/problem.

Comment: oh sorry, you are right I was going to mention the error meanwhile I forgot :D the error is : NotImplementedError: Layer ModuleWrapper has arguments in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config`.

Comment: @Noushin, Can you share complete code to replicate your issue?so that we can try to help you. Thanks!